# what are cofigure options for log4php to disable logging?

Tags: debugging, log4php

This method Logger::configure($options); of log4php is used to configure logging options. How should $options argument look like to disable log4php completely?

Comment: found it, just pass it this array and it's off
array('rootLogger' => array('level' => 'WARN'))

Answer (score 0):

This works for me:

```
$options = array('threshold'=>'off');
Logger::configure($options);
```